# Correcting SOAP Fault Method not Implemented Errors

Tags: soap, curl, paypal, paypal-sandbox, soap-client

OK, not sure what this problem is. I am trying to post an API request to PayPal via cURL and I get the following result. Is there something that I am missing in my call that would cause this?

According to PayPal, the call is correct and it works fine when I use the PHP cURL wrapper functions...Weird.

Thanks for helping!

```
curl https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/2.0/ -H "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID: api1.sitetest.com" -H "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD: 111222222UH24" -H "X-PAYPAL-DEVICE-IPADDRESS: 170.10.125.52" -H "X-PAYPAL-MESSAGE-PROTOCOL: SOAP11" -H "X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID: APP-80W284485P519543T" -E "/Users/Me/Library/PayPal_Keys/cert_key_pem.txt" -d "<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:SOAP-ENC=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/\" xmlns:SOAP-ENV=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema\" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/\"><SOAP-ENV:Header /><SOAP-ENV:Body><CreateAndSendInvoiceRequest><requestEnvelope><errorLanguage>en_US</errorLanguage></requestEnvelope><invoice><merchantEmail>sweet@sweetsounds.com</merchantEmail><payerEmail>me@testsite.com</payerEmail><businessName>Test Business, Inc.</businessName><logoURL></logoURL><itemList><item><name>Test Item</name><quantity>2</quantity><unitPrice>5.79</unitPrice><taxName>sales</taxName><taxRate>6.0</taxRate></item></itemList></invoice></CreateAndSendInvoiceRequest></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>"
```

Returns

```
<SOAP-ENV:Fault><faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Client</faultcode><faultstring>Method not implemented</faultstring></SOAP-ENV:Fault>
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved this. PayPal changed the sandbox api url for this particular call and did not update that in their docs.

Comment: I just received this error this afternoon. What is the new sandbox api url?

Answer (score 0):

new url for sandbox is "https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/2.0/". You can test your commands here